# Replace text in Column with code from another sheet in text partial matches

Tags: regex, vba, excel, match

I am looking for a way to scan a column in a sheet and if the code matches with a longer version of the code on a separate sheet, replace the short code with the longer code. For example on sheet1 in column 1 rows 1-10 contain code "ABCD". Search sheet 2 column 1 and find "Code_Type_ABCD" and replace "ABCD" in sheet one with the value "Code_Type_ABCD" from sheet 2. There are 50 different codes on sheet 1 that will need to be searched for and replaced with values from sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't really write the code from scratch for you, but I was bored...

```
Sub FindInString()

    Dim rngCell_1 As Range
    Dim rngCell_2 As Range

    'loop through sheet 1
    For Each rngCell_1 In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10")
        'loop through sheet 2
        For Each rngCell_2 In Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A50")
            'if have found the range
            If InStr(0, rngCell_2.Text, rngCell_1.Text) <> 0 Then
                'change the value
                rngCell_1.Value = rngCell_2.Value
            End If
        Next rngCell_2
    Next rngCell_1

End Sub
```